# How do I normalise the input value for acosf or asinf?

Tags: c, trigonometry, math.h

I need to obtain an inverse cosine and inverse sine from the result of a series of other calculations. If my input value is outside the range -1 to 1 then `acosf` or `asinf` return `nan`, which is expected given the definition of the function.

How should I adjust the value so that it falls within the acceptable range, but still gives the correct answer? In the spreadsheet I am using to check my calculations this normalisation is happening behind the scenes so nan is not returned.

I think I have to do something like, for acosf, add cos(pi) until the value falls into the range, but I'd like some confirmation or advice please.

Comment: What is the correct answer, if not "nan"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no normalization process.  If the answer is outside [-1,+1], then the preceding calculations are broken.

One exception is if floating-point inaccuracies have lead to a value such as 1.00001.  In cases such as these, it is probably safe to clamp the input to the valid range.

Comment: Ahhhh - the value was very close to 1. That must have been it. I assumed it was just starting to go out of the range, but a rounding / floating point inaccuracy makes more sense.. Thanks very much. It's been years since I did any trig, very rusty now...